# Joomla | Article Manager is not displaying Articles

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-module

I am using Joomla 1.5.21 for my website. When I logged in via my Super Administrator account and goes to Article Manager then it does not display any article.
Please help me how to fix this problem. I will be very thankful to all of you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In database ,check whether the #_content table is empty.If its empty create a new article.